# Mongo handle in meteor 0.6.5+

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In the previous version, 0.6.4, I can use `Meteor._RemoteCollectionDriver.mongo.db` to access to mongodb directly. Because I need to use Mongo's Grid to store files, which I cannot do easily with Meteor collections. With the new version, `Meteor._RemoteCollectionDriver.mongo.db` is not available anymore. Does anyone know where can I have that?

Thanks

Comment: +1 Good reference for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they've moved to a singleton style class, see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo-livedata/remote_collection_driver.js.

Be warned this isn't upgrade proof either like before, as with all the methods beginning with `_`:

```
MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver
```

Comment: That was it, I tried it before, it didnt work for my case. I thought that was due to mongodb handle. But no, it comes from Future code. Thanks anyway.